# powershell comparing multiple arrays

Tags: powershell

I've a case where multiple arrays need to be compared.There is one master array that contains all the elements that the child arrays have and also some extra elements.

In below example, `$a` is the master array and `$b`, `$c` are child arrays.
I need to compare these arrays and get the list of those extra elements in `$a` that are not present in `$b` and `$c`.
Practically, in my case there are 10  child arrays and a master array.

```
$a="dhaw","roh","kohl","faf","abd","steyn","gupt","baz","kane","benn","brendn","joyc"
$b="roh","dhaw","kohl"
$c="steyn","abd","faf","roh","dhaw"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i know about the compare-object but that seems to work only for 2 arrays.i read that regex could be helpful in this case but have very little idea of how that works.

Comment: You need to look at using the `-contains` or `-notcontains` operator for the subject array and an array element you want to test

Comment: I can't see how regex is going to be helpful here.

Comment: `Compare-Objects` seems to support an array of `-DifferenceObject`s.

Answer (score 4):

A viable solution could be using `-notcontains` operator as suggested by arco444, cycle through `$a` array elements and check if they are contained at least in one of the other arrays.

Here is a slice of code

```
foreach($a_value in $a) {
    if (($b -notcontains $a_value) -and ($c -notcontains $a_value)) {
        "$a_value is extra"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```powershell
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject ($b + $c)
```

If you just want to get raw objects:

```powershell
(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject ($b + $c) |
    Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}).InputObject
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex solution:

```
$a="dhaw","roh","kohl","faf","abd","steyn","gupt","baz","kane","benn","brendn","joyc"
$b="roh","dhaw","kohl"
$c="steyn","abd","faf","roh","dhaw"

$b_regex = ‘(?i)^(‘ + (($b |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)$’
$c_regex = ‘(?i)^(‘ + (($c |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)$’
```

Then, for elements of $a that aren't in $b:

```
$a -notmatch $b_regex 

faf
abd
steyn
gupt
baz
kane
benn
brendn
joyc
```

For elements of $a that aren't in $c:

```
$a -notmatch $c_regex

kohl
gupt
baz
kane
benn
brendn
joyc
```

And for elements of $a that aren't in $b or $c:

```
$a -notmatch $b_regex -notmatch $c_regex

gupt
baz
kane
benn
brendn
joyc
```

[Runtime Regex](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/18/speed-up-array-comparisons-in-powershell-with-a-runtime-regex.aspx)

Note: this is just provided for demonstration for the people who left comments about it.  This substantially faster than the `-contains / -notcontains` solutions, but for a single instance comparison it's probably overkill. It can produce substantial performance gains inside a loop where you're comparing one array to many other arrays.